# Why call scope.$digest() after $compile(element)(scope) in unit testing

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

Below is a very common generic scenario used for testing directive:

```
var element,scope;

beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope,$compile) {
  scope = $rootScope.$new()
  element = angular.element('<div my-directive></div>')
  $compile(element)(scope)
  scope.$digest(); //why?
}))
```

I understand `$compile(element)` returns a function that take a scope parameter and provides it to the element's directive. I also understand that `scope.$digest()` executes the digest loop and start dirty-checking. With all that said, my question is why you have to call the `scope.$digest` after calling `$compile` to make everything works in this situation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a generic code for testing a directive. `$Compile` binds template with scope and executes `link` function and `$digest`/`$apply` refreshes bindings for models that might have been modified by `link`.
When you call `$compile` inside `ng-click` handler or in controller function, the whole execution is run inside a `$digest` loop. Angular is built in such a way that dynamically added items (while executing this loop) are executed in same cycle. That is why you don't actually notice the difference and don't realize the need for binding evaluations after compilation. However it's way different in unit tests, where you should tell angular to execute a `$digest` cycle manually. This often results in problems when testing `$q` promises, for example.