# Change parent scope variable on angular directive where parent has isolated scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following directive:

```
<some-directive key="123"></some-directive>
```

in the directive:

```
angular.module('app').directive('someDirective', ['someFactory', '$compile', '$timeout', function(PatientFactory, $compile, $timeout){

    return {
                scope:{

                    customer: "="
                },
                controller: _controller,
                templateUrl: 'components/sometemplate.html',
                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {   


                }
            };
```

I have another directive based on key... once get fetched customer, I add an attribute, set customer with result and recompile. Its not working

```
angular.module('app').directive('key', ['someFactory', '$compile', '$timeout', function(PatientFactory, $compile, $timeout){
     return{

                link: function(scope, el, attr){

                    //if key provided from, we need to get the customer based on this key.
                    if (attr.key) {                        
                        scope.someFactory.getCustomerByKey(attr.key).then(function (res) {    

                            el.attr('customer', res);                            
                            var fn = $compile(el);
                            return function(scope){
                                fn(scope);
                            };

                        });

                    }else{

                       //error

                    }


                }
```

I can see the customer getting updated in the $parent scope in dev console, but the view is showing {{customer}} instead of outputting the customer.

Comment: your plunker shows an error that might lead you to find the answer: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Object' is unexpected, expecting []] at column 9 of the expression [[object Object]] starting at [Object]].`

Comment: Any idea how to fix this error?

Comment: what you are trying to do isn't really going to work.  you can't pass an **object** through `el.attr`.  What you seem to want is `customer="{{customer}}"` but that won't work, since there isn't a `$scope.customer` element on the parent.  on top of that, your `el.attr` call is coming out as `customer="[object object]"` (expected behavior, but not the behavior you want.).  you could pass a **string** to the other directive, if that's all you wanted to render....

Answer (score 0):

You should use `scope.$apply` after `$compile`.

See this answer: [Why call scope.$digest() after $compile(element)(scope) in unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31373772/why-call-scope-digest-after-compileelementscope-in-unit-testing)

---

**UPDATE**

Another culprit might be `priority` - [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile). You should set the priority of the `key` directive higher than `some-directive` so that user data is available when link function of `some-directive` is executing.

---

**UPDATE 2**

I think you should do what you want (call the factory based on key) in the controller of the directive. Please see this plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/BH3bDD?p=preview.

Comment: Try tinkering with `priority` as per my response. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: If this doesn't work, can you provide me with the result that you would like to achieve?

Comment: here is a plunk. Not working...https://plnkr.co/edit/9wab34miZdlQ21Jgp4k3?p=preview

Comment: Please see my update #2. I think it would be easier for you to do this in the controller, unless there's a specific reason not to do this.

Comment: Update #2 will not work because this will be shared across mutiple directives